# Disable swipe on Viewpager, allow only Swipe on pagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

I am facing a problem on disabling the swipe gesture on viewpager fragment. Right now, I am using custom viewpager to disable the swipe gesture.

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}
}
```

As result, this also will disable pagerTitleStrip. The reason I need to disable swipe gesture as one of my fragment contains a feature to remove item by swiping. It is possible to disable swipe only on viewpager but not on pagerTitleStrip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PagerTitleStrip only shows title.
use PagerTabStrip instead of PagerTitleStrip.

Comment: Thank. It solved my problem. It may not be swipeable, but the pagerTabStrip is clickable.